# Is it possible to get Gmail Password sent to my recovery email address?

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I want my Gmail password to come to my recovery email address without changing the password.

Is it possible. If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 9):

No. The reason Google doesn’t do this is because it presents a significant security risk. In order to send you your password, Google would have to store it in plain text, which means any attacker who manages to gain access to even part of Google's database of passwords would have a field day.

Google stores your passwords with a strong one-way hash—they are not retrievable, by them or by you. So the password reset is the only option.

Comment: Doesn't even need to be a security breach at Google. What if someone has access to your recovery email address? Or intercepts the email while it passes from server to server?

Comment: yep - that too, Al